# Programmatic routing and "open link in a new tab" option in VueJS 2.6

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a button that sends me to a new page if I click on it. It looks like that and work just fine  (simplified example):

```
<v-btn :to="{name: 'route-name'}">GO</v-btn>
```

I can left click on it and it will open in the current tab or I can right click on it, select the "Open link in a new tab" option and it will open in a new tab.

I would like to achieve the same behavior with programmatic routing but I can't find out how. I tried something like that:

```
<template>
    ...    
    <v-btn @click="goto">GO</v-btn>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    ...
    methods: {
        goto(){
            this.$router.push({name: 'route-name'})
        }
    }
    ...
</script>
```

This works fine when I want to open the new page in the current tab (left click) but when right clicking the option of "open link in a new tab" does not appear.

Is there a way to make it appear ?

Note that I don't want to always open it in a new tab but I want to be able to do both (open in current tab or new tab)

Comment: You can use route.resolve to get href value (https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-resolve) and open new tab with window.open method.
So the solution would be something like this `const route = this.$router.resolve({ name: 'route-name' }); window.open(route.href, '_blank');`

Comment: It works but it opens the page in a new tab. What I need is: left click -> open in current tab and right click -> show contextual menu with the "open link in a new tab" option. This way I can easily choose whether I open the page in the current tab or in a new tab

Comment: I believe that in order to open link in new tab, your link needs to know where it should go. If you need some custom checking for your route, you can make it as computed property that returns object for your route (or put everything in data model if you don't need computed property).